# If currentTime is between two specific timestamps

Tags: java, swing, datetime

I am currently trying to code a school schedule. I am tierd of always checking that paper format that we got at school one of the first days at school. So this is my problem:

I want to display a label(info about the lesson) at a certain point of the day. What I mean by this is that if the clock is 10:20 it would show English lesson, and if the clock is 09:32 it would display Math or something. If I havent explained this properly I will give you a code example that dont work, but adresses my needs:

**TimeLabel is a clock displayed on a label!**

```
if (String.valueOf(TimeLabel.getText()).isBetween(10:20, 11:30)){
    Display code here
}
```

What I can do is:

```
if (TimeLabel.getText().equals("10:20", "10:21", "10:22"))
```

All the way up to the wanted time, but that takes forever when I am going to adress the time from 7:55 -> 15:00

The reason because I am not just setting it to change when the lesson start is because if I open my program mid lesson it wont show as I want it to.

Comment: I think your best bet is to do some research on working with time in Java rather than then starting out with stackoverflow question. Read this article: http://www.javaworld.com/jw-03-2001/jw-0330-time.html

Comment: Also, try this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaDateTimeAPI/article.html

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this, would be to create two date object representing the starting time and the ending time. You can parse Strings to Dates using a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Then you can use the `before()` and `after()` methods of [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

Something like

```
Date start = ...// Will leave this up to you to find out how to parse
Date end   = ...//

Date now   = new Date() //get current date from system time or parse from the label

if(now.after(start) && now.before(end))
{
    //do some stuff
}
```